# Flair not displaying: All Image URLs must start with HTTPS

Tags: bug, flair, ssl, combined-flair

When I go to my profile flair, I get the following link:

```
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/5014328">
<img src="https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/5014328.png" width="208" height="58" alt="profile for NSNoob on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites" title="profile for NSNoob on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites">
</a>
```

Which should show up as:

[image: profile for NSNoob on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

But the flair image does not show in the profile and gives following error in "Edit Profile" mode:

[image]

This is how profile looks after saving the changes:

[image]

As you can see, the profile flair image is not displaying. However if I replace:

```
<img src="https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/5014328.png"
```

With

```
<img src="https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/5014328.png"
```

Then it starts displaying on my profile.

If Stackoverflow is no longer displaying http images in profile, then they should update the flair menu to generate image urls with HTTPS instead.

I have reproduced this on:

1. History SE
2. Science Fiction and Fantasy SE
3. Stack Overflow

My client config are:

1. Google Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) using Windows 8.1
2. Google Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) using macOS Sierra 10.12.3

EDIT: As Rene has shared, this has already been [pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343298/4029561) weeks ago. [Official reply](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343276/https-only-images/343298#comment445009_343298) to request of updating the flair html was :

> FWIW, 3 developers thought this was safe to change. I was the first.
> It's been fixed 3 times...and reverted 3 times :) As soon as it's
> valid on child SE metas and their URL rendering kicks over, so shall
> the flair

Comment: I expect this to be an issue caused by the desire to serve all pages over https. IIRC there have database updates to replace http with https in posts. Maybe the userprofiles have not been included in those updates?

Comment: @rene I didn't know SE had plans to switch to HTTPS so this is news to me.

Comment: Here is the [MSO post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343276/https-only-images) but introducing https started wayback in 2012 or so.

Comment: @rene Thanks. That specific post is fairly recent I see. Guess they did not consider flair images when they rolled out the image url changes. [Arul Kumar has already requested the same](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343298/4029561)

Comment: There is an issue with flair in userprofiles. I recalled a comment from Nick and I found it: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343276/https-only-images/343298#comment445009_343298

Comment: @rene Yes I was just adding that comment to the post. Should I leave this post or delete it then as it is already in notice of SE team?

Comment: It is fine to have it here as well, in case the users across the network stumble on the same issue.